# Power Automate - Unable to access Folder structure of mapped SharePoint site with custom ports on SharePoint server 2019 using On Premise Data Gateway

Tags: sharepoint-server, flow, power-automate, mapped-folder, file-system

I have mapped a SharePoint 2019 site library on SharePoint Server File system and using On-Premises Data Gateway, I want to create files in that mapped network folder using Power Automate.

If I mapped the SharePoint site with default port 80 and tried to create file (having root folder - `\\ow-sp19-srv\Emails` ) using Power Automate then it is successfully created.

However, If I mapped a SharePoint site having custom port (e.g. 4040) and after creating File System connection in MS Flow with following root folder path `\\ow-sp19-srv@4040\Emails` then I'm unable to access the Folder system it shows following error:

[image]

And If I tried to run the flow with putting the same Folder path manually then I get following error during Flow run:

> The requested action could not be completed. Check your request
> parameters to make sure the path
> '\ow-sp19-srv@4040\Emails/Testing Email Subject.eml'
> exists on your file system. clientRequestId:
> ab2840ad-8b64-4ef2-928d-bd5c17d42c20

Troubleshooting steps already performed:

1. Updated Gateway to June 2020 release.
2. Tried to open the same UNC path from my local system using same credential that was used in File System connection of Power Automate.
3. Made the ports opened to internet in Firewall.

Any help is much appreciated with respect to Creating Proper connection or troubleshooting via Power Automate logging if available.

Comment: Is they're a reason you're trying to map to SharePoint and use a File Server connection instead of using a SharePoint trigger/action?

Comment: There is a flow that does some workflow processing of system and sends an email and we need to save this whole email as an eml file in SharePoint Library. However, we are unable to save it in SP On Premise getting "Resource Not Found" error. So I mapped the SP Library on SP Server.